# Commuting Homeomorphism on Unit Circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given that $f$ is an orientation preserving homeomorphism of the unit circle such that $f(z^n) = f(z)^n$ for all $z$ in the unit circle, $n > 1$. Prove that $f$ is a rotation.

Well, if it were an irrational rotation instead of the map $z^n$, then one can lift the maps to its universal cover, and the functional equation would now become $f(z + \alpha) = f(z) + \alpha$. Now we use the fact that $m*\alpha$ is dense modulo $1$, and continuity shall yield that the $f$ is a translation.

The reason this works there is because the orbit of points are dense, but in the case of the map $z^n$ I’m not quite sure how to proceed.

I was reading the paper - ‘Automorphisms of Rational Maps’ by Curtis McMullen and I found this statement in a remark in that paper. Understanding this becomes sort of important because this ensures that such maps are rigid, in other words, their conjugates can but rotate them. He proposes three such rigid models in that paper, one happens to be irrational rotation (Elliptic Model), second happens to be the map $z^n$ (Hyperbolic Model), and third is called the Parabolic Model given by a particular möbius transformation composed with a polynomial.

Comment: And what did you try ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I tried doing it the way I did for irrational rotation in place of the map $z^n$. I got stuck.

Comment: ... and would you mind explaining what is this way (by editing your question) ? If you don't explain where you are stuck, we can't help you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I edited the post. Have a look.

Comment: Is a condition “for all $n$” missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=1$, the functional equation is trivial and hence any $f$ will do, i.e., $f$ need not be a rotation!

So suppose $n>1$. A somewhat similar argument to what you tried works as follows:
Let $\zeta=\exp(2\pi I/n)$ be the standard $n$th root of unity. Similarly, let $\eta=\exp(2\pi I/n^2)$.
We see that $f(1)$ must be an $(n-1)$th root of unity $\xi$.
It follows that $f(\zeta^k)=\zeta^k\xi$, i.e. $f$ is just multiplication by $\xi$ for those $n$ points. Then $g(z):=\frac{f(z)}{z\xi}$ can only take values on the arc between $\zeta^{-1}$ and $\zeta$.

Next, note that $f(\eta^k)^n=f(\zeta^k)=\zeta^k\xi$. Hence $g(\eta^k)$ is a root of unity on said arc, hence must be equal to $1$.

The same way, we find by induction on $r$ that $g(z)=1$ for all $n^r$th roots of unity.
By a density argument, $g$ is constant, as was to be shown.

Comment: Where are you using the fact that $f$ is an orientation preserving homeomorphism? Because we obviously have other candidates for $f(z)$, for instance $f$ can be the complex conjugation or any of $z^n$. Your argument doesn’t seem to eliminate them.

Comment: I also don’t see how $f$ is just multiplication by $\xi$ for those $n$ points.